# Getting "ERR syntax error" on set using node-redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I am unable to set and get key in redis using node-redis. But set and get works well when using redis-cli.
This is my code:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const util = require('util');

const GLOBAL_KEY = 'lambda-test';
const redisOptions = {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT
}

try{
    test();
}
catch(err) {
    console.log('catch err ' + err);
}

async function test() {
    var client = redis.createClient(redisOptions);
    client.on("error", function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
    client.get = util.promisify(client.get);
    client.set = util.promisify(client.set);
    await client.set("ke", "test1", redis.print).catch(function(err){console.log('err: '+ err);});
    await client.get("ke", redis.print).catch(function(err){console.log('err: '+ err);});
}
```

Output:

```
err: ReplyError: ERR syntax error
err: ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
```

Can't figure what the reason is, can anyone help me figure what I am missing?

Update:
I tried using bind, but no luck:

```
    client.get = util.promisify(client.get).bind(client);
    client.set = util.promisify(client.set).bind(client);
```

Also I have enabled the DEBUG to get extra logs:

```
2021-04-20T07:48:36.279Z Queueing set for next server connection.
2021-04-20T07:48:36.303Z Stream connected XXXXX:6379 id 0
2021-04-20T07:48:36.303Z Checking server ready state...
2021-04-20T07:48:36.304Z Send XXXXXX:6379 id 0: *1
$4
info

2021-04-20T07:48:36.305Z Net read XXXXX:6379 id 0
2021-04-20T07:48:36.306Z Redis server ready.
2021-04-20T07:48:36.306Z on_ready called XXXXX:6379 id 0
2021-04-20T07:48:36.307Z Sending offline command: set
2021-04-20T07:48:36.307Z Send XXXXX:6379 id 0: *4
$3
set
$2
ke
$5
test1
$187
function print (err, reply) {
    if (err) {
        // A error always begins with Error:
        console.log(err.toString());
    } else {
        console.log('Reply: ' + reply);
    }
}

2021-04-20T07:48:36.307Z Net read XXXXX:6379 id 0
err: ReplyError: ERR syntax error
2021-04-20T07:48:36.309Z Send XXXXX:6379 id 0: *3
$3
get
$2
ke
$187
function print (err, reply) {
    if (err) {
        // A error always begins with Error:
        console.log(err.toString());
    } else {
        console.log('Reply: ' + reply);
    }
}

2021-04-20T07:48:36.310Z Net read XXXXX:6379 id 0
err: ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
```

Comment: Try `client.get = util.promisify(client.get).bind(client)`

Comment: Thanks that didn't help, please check the update

Comment: Use  `const data = await client.get("ke"); console.log(data);`

Comment: it returns `undefined`

Comment: I think if you want to properly bind client.get you should do util.promisify(client.get.bind(client)) - ie this is the reference to the client.get function that should be bound, not the function returned by the promisify method. Not sure that would solve your issue though.

Comment: I think in `util.promisify(client.get.bind(client))` the `.bind(client)` is redundant as the `get` is referenced via client already. However I tried it and it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: It is not redundant, If you omit bind(client), you're just passing promisify() a reference to the get() function and the binding to client is lost.

Comment: Try to remove `redis.print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for suggestion. I posted the question as issue on the repo https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis/issues/1599 and got the answer from [leibale](https://github.com/leibale):

```
async function test() {
    const client = redis.createClient(redisOptions);
    client.on("error", function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
    client.get = util.promisify(client.get).bind(client);
    client.set = util.promisify(client.set).bind(client);

    try {
        console.log('SET reply:', await client.set("ke", "test1"));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

    try {
        console.log('GET reply:', await client.get("ke"));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } 
}
```

The issue was `bind` and use of `redis.print` as a callback